# i am not getting any error in my java code but still it is unable to run?

Tags: java, function

I don't know why my defined function is not working smoothly.

[in this I am trying to build a function to convert a binary number to a decimal number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7oab.png)

```
public class binarrytodec {
public static void bintodec(int n){
    int p=0;
    int dec=0;
    while(n>0){
        int ld=n%10;
        dec = dec + (ld*(int)Math.pow(2, p));
        p++;
        n=n%10;
    }
    System.out.print(dec);

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    bintodec(1110001);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Post the code, not a picture of the code.  No-one can run your picture.

Comment: I know that VS Code is a great editor, but honestly I'd suggest you to use IntelliJ Idea to write and run/debug java code.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothly"? Please include current behavior and desired behavior. From the little bit of information you've provided I think it can be reasonably assumed that it's stuck in an infinite loop, so start by trying to figure out why the condition is never `false`.

Comment: Try changing `n=n%10` to `n=n/10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is not division, it's a remainder operation - it shows how much is left *after* integer division. `1 % 10 == 1`. Thus your `n` is never becoming 0, and your code enters an infinite loop.